# How to correctly map random texture to an object?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

So I want to map the texture on the left to the object on the right. And because this texture was taken from the Internet and was not designed for this model you can see a lot of artifacts (**blue lines**). How can I map this texture to an object correctly so that this texture will be seen OK from all sides (except the bottom of the model)?

[image]

And if I can't do that then what is the best way to paint this texture yourself? Texture paint or maybe there are better (easier for the newbie) ways to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using Box mapping in the image node? That allows you to blend the texture a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Once unwrapped your mesh, go to the UV Editor and enlarge, rotate, the mesh to achieve what you're looking for.
Is easier this way, but also you can do the same on the Node editor with a:
"Texture cordinate" plugged into a "Mapping" plugged into the "image texture" which contains the image you're using.

Steps:

(in the node editor) Add a texture cordinate and mapping tab

Connect the UV slot of the Texture Cordinate into the Mapping

Then, plug the mapping into "Image Texture" node which contains the image you're using.

Now, tweak the rotation and size on the Mapping tab to achieve what you're looking for.

I hope this works for you.